# How to get URL from files stored in firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, async-await

I try to get URL of pictures stored in the Firebase Storage.
Following the reading of Firebase's documentation, I understand that I need to use the function getDownloadURL() which return a promise.
The following code is the closest solution that I get for the moment.

```
getUserPicture(data: UserItem[]) {
data.forEach( async  (item) => {
  const storage = firebase.storage();
  const pathReference = storage.ref(item.userId + '/profile.jpg'); 

  item.picture = await pathReference.getDownloadURL()
  .then((url) => {
      return url.toString();
   })
   .catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);
   });
   console.log('TEST : item.picture: ' + item.picture + ' for user: ' + item.lastname );  
});
```

}

The console.log return the URL of the profile picture for each user.
Unfortunately, the call of the function getUserPicture() does not get the job done (item.picture are still undefined). I think it's because the top function should be async in order to wait the process in the loop.

Do you know how to resolve such problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use async/await within a forEach() loop, see ["JavaScript: async/await with forEach()"](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404) and ["Using async/await with a forEach loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop).

And since you execute a variable number of calls to the asynchronous `getDownloadURL()` method in parallel, you should use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), as follows:

```
async getUserPicture(data: UserItem[]) {

    const storage = firebase.storage();
    const promises = [];

    data.forEach((item) => {
        const pathReference = storage.ref(item.userId + '/profile.jpg');
        promises.push(pathReference.getDownloadURL());
    });

    const urlsArray = await Promise.all(promises)

});
```

Comment: Thanks Renaud. It means that I will need to do another loop after the promise.all in order to assign the right user.picture  to each user (by using urlsArray). If my understanding is right, I can't do it directly in the first loop.

Comment: Yes you are right. You cannot do it in the first loop: The goal of this first loop is to build an array of Promises that are passed to `Promise.all()`which is asynchronous. It's only when the execution of `Promise.all()` is complete that you have the array of URLs.